# .Net Core 3.1 Worker as Window Service Error [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

Tags: c#, .net-core, window, backgroundworker

Unable to install .Net Core Worker as Window Service

Error:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

Command used to install exe:

```
>sc.exe create MyService binpath="C:\MyService.exe" displayname="MyPostWS" start= auto

>sc.exe start DMSBatchService
```

Comment: You create "MyService", but then start "DMSBatchService"?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the given information, you could try a few things to check the issue.

First, check the logs in the event viewer.

Check the service is located at the specified path C:\MyService.exe.

Check whether your service has the necessary permissions like if it is running under a service account.

and last but not the least check your code by putting some logs